How do I prune my daracaena corn plant
My Dracaena (corn plant) leaves need to be trimmed. They are about 3 1/2 ft tall from soil to the tip of each leaf.

Hi Angie,  welcome to the site. Its best to post  a photo.

Do you want to trim burnt edges? Do you want to chop and reroot in water?
